# Set range to sum from pivot table using date from different worksheet

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to define a range of numbers to sum, using a fixed cell as the start and using a cell (containing a date) in a different worksheet to define the end of the range.

I am importing data to my workbook using a pivot table (there is too much data for a regular table to import).  The data is a sum of loads hauled by truck by day.  Column A contains individual days, Column B is the loads the truck 1 hauled on that day, Column C is truck 2, etc.   I have a separate worksheet for each truck, where I want to put the total loads hauled from the start of the chart (for this case, cell B3) to the date of a repair.  The date of repair will be placed in a cell in the truck worksheet.  I am running into trouble finding a way to define the address of the cell for the end of the range.

I have tried `=Sum('NAME'!B3:Vlookup(…))` and `=SUM('NAME'!B3:CELL("address",INDEX(…,MATCH(…,...:...,0))))`.

Independently, the Vlookup returns the value of the cell, so I understand why that doesn't work.  The `=INDEX(MATCH)` returns the desired address when used by itself.  However, I tried it in the SUM function by itself (not defining a range) and it returned #VALUE.

Comment: Use SUMIFS and braket the dates.

Comment: @ScottCraner , I am trying to write a formula that will allow future input to be calculated

Comment: Why are you trying to find the end of the range, by your definition a simple sum will work.  `=SUM(B:B)` sum will ignore the title text and only sum the values.

Comment: @ScottCraner , I have data from 2017 to today (and still being added).  If a repair was conducted in Jan 2018, it will have a different sum of loads than one conducted in Jan 2019.  I want to be able to write a date in a different worksheet, and have the loads from the beginning of the table to THAT DATE summed up.

Comment: Then you are back to a SUMIFS(): `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<=" & [YOURDATECELL])`

Comment: @ScottCraner , that worked, thank you!